# Django REST Multiple Models (base_name & queryset) error

Tags: python, django, django-models, djangorestframework

Estoy intentando usar el [Django REST Multiple Models](https://github.com/Axiologue/DjangoRestMultipleModels) y he creado los modelos y la `ViewSet`. Pero al intentar entrar en la URL de la API, me saca un error:

```
'base_name' argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name 
from the viewset, as it does not have a '.queryset' attribute
```

¿Alguien sabe indicarme que me falta? Ya que he seguido la documentación y tengo la misma estructura que indica, pero al ser un poco novato con la API de Django no sé por donde me viene este error.

Archivo `api/views.py`:

```
class PreguntasRespuestasViewset(MultipleModelAPIView):

    queryList = [
        (Pregunta.objects.all(), PreguntaSerializer),
        (Respuesta.objects.all(), RespuestaSerializer),
    ]
```

Archivo `api/urls.py`:

```
router.register(r'faqs', PreguntasRespuestasViewset)
```

Archivo `api/serializers.py`:

```
class PreguntaSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pregunta
        fields = ('id', 'asunto', 'descripcion', 'fecha_publicacion')


class RespuestaSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Respuesta
        fields = ('Pregunta', 'contenido', 'mejor_respuesta')
```

Archivo `models.py`:

```
class Pregunta(models.Model):
    asunto = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    descripcion = models.TextField()
    fecha_publicacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.asunto

    def publicado_hoy(self):
        return self.fecha_publicacion.date() == timezone.now().date()
    publicado_hoy.boolean = True
    publicado_hoy.short_description = 'Preguntado hoy'


class Respuesta(models.Model):
    Pregunta = models.ForeignKey(Pregunta)
    contenido = models.TextField()
    mejor_respuesta = models.BooleanField("Respuesta preferida", default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.contenido
```

**EDITO:** Si escribo un `base_name` en la URL:

```
router.register(r'faqs', PreguntasRespuestasViewset, base_name='PreguntasRespuestas')
```

Y me saca el siguiente error:

```
as_view() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

Answer (score 3):

El parámetro `base_name` no es de `register`, se genera automáticamente cuando tienes un `queryset`. En tu caso, como no lo estás declarando, lo que deberías hacer es usar `as_view()`.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ faqs', PreguntasRespuestasViewset.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: Complementando la respuesta de @user3626118  en algunas ocasiones debes adicionar el (**base_name**), algo como esto:
`urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ faqs', PreguntasRespuestasViewset.as_view(), base_name="PreguntasRespuestas),
]`